# Extremely slow graph building/model compilation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In tensorflow, I am working with the following recurrent autoencoder model which gives me headaches:

```
class FRAEEncoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, input_shape, latent_dim,   layer_config, **kwargs):
    super(FRAEEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.SetupLayers(input_shape, latent_dim, layer_config)

def SetupLayers(self, input_shape, latent_dim, layer_config):
    self.encoder = []
    activations  = layer_config["activations"]
    num_neuron   = layer_config["neurons"]
    for i, act in enumerate(activations):
        if i == 0:
            self.encoder.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_neuron[i], activation=act, input_shape=(input_shape,)))
        else:
            self.encoder.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_neuron[i], activation=act))

    if len(activations) > 0:
        self.encoder.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim, "swish"))
    else:
        self.encoder.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim, "swish", input_shape=(input_shape,)))



def call(self, inputs, state):
    # encoder
    encoded = tf.concat([inputs, state], axis=-1)

    for lrs in self.encoder:
        encoded = lrs(encoded)

    new_output = encoded
    return new_output

class FRAEDecoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self,   output_dim, layer_config, **kwargs):
    super(FRAEDecoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.SetupLayers(output_dim, layer_config)

def SetupLayers(self,  output_dim, layer_config):
    self.decoder = []
    activations  = layer_config["activations"]
    num_neuron   = layer_config["neurons"]

    for i, act in reversed(list(enumerate(activations))):
        self.decoder.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_neuron[i],activation=act))

    self.decoder.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_dim, activation='linear'))


def call(self, encoded, state):
    y = tf.concat([encoded, state], axis=1)
    for lrs in self.decoder:
        y = lrs(y)

    #update output and state
    new_output = y  # Result of some operations on `combined`
    new_state  = tf.concat([new_output, state[:, :-tf.shape(new_output)[-1]]], axis=-1)
    return new_output, new_state




class FRAE(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,  output_dim, latent_dim, ht,  layer_config={"activations":    [],"neurons":[]}, bypass=False, codebook=None, **kwargs):
        super(FRAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.ht = ht
        self.encoder = FRAEEncoder(output_dim, latent_dim, layer_config,     name=self.name+"_Encoder")
        self.decoder = FRAEDecoder(output_dim, layer_config, name=self.name+"_Decoder")
        self.quantizer = VectorQuantization(codebook=codebook, name=self.name+"_VQ")
        self.bypass = bypass


def SetQuantizer(self, codebook):
    self.quantizer.SetQuantizer(codebook)

def call(self, x):
    if not self.bypass:
        state = tf.zeros(shape=(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.shape(x)[2] * self.ht))

        x_unstacked = tf.unstack(x, num=7999, axis=1)

        output_list = [None] * len(x_unstacked)
        for i, inputs in enumerate(x_unstacked):
            encoded = self.encoder(inputs, state)
            encoded_q = self.quantizer(encoded)
            decoded, state = self.decoder(encoded_q, state)
            output_list[i] = decoded

        outputs = tf.stack(output_list, axis=1)

        return outputs

    else:
        return x
```

Building this model takes forever, like 12 minutes currently. I am not sure why. A previous recurrent model I build, which is similar but worse in implementation, builds almost instantly. Training this model, after building it, is rather quick and not unusually slow (actually a little bit faster than my previous implementation that builds quicker).
Does anyone know the reason? Can I somehow speed this up? This slows down development considerably.